# Why is Logic App creating another run when the http action is taking more than 1 min to complete?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In my logic app, when my HTTP action takes more than 1 minute to complete, it creates a new run, while the existing run is also running in parallel.

Is there a way to ensure the logic app doesn't create a new run in this case? In addition, what is the option to increase the retry time?

Could you please help me with both options to disable retry and increase retry time?

Comment: Can you show us your flow? Do you mean that your app is calling another endpoint and retrying? If so, do you control that endpoint? Timeouts in LA typically start at two minutes so clarification is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can **enable concurrency control** **in** your http **trigger** to limit the number of concurrent Logic Apps instances.

Thanks  @Oleg Zhuk for the concurrency control [document](https://www.virtocommerce.org/t/how-to-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-logic-apps-instances/161)

- In logic app http trigger, go to settings and **enable concurrency control then set limit to 1**. This will allow you to run only one instance of logic app workflow.
  [image]
- By default retry policy will be enabled and that sends up to 4 retries at exponentially increasing intervals. These intervals are limited to between 5 and 45 seconds and scale by 7.5 seconds.
- If you want **to disable retry policy** you can **select none** in your **action settings**.

[image]

-You can increase retry time using retry time of type **Exponential Interval** and **Fixed Interval**
[image]

With exponential interval retry policy, the default maximum delay **for the consumption** plan is **1 day**. **For standard plan** default max delay is **1 hour** for exponential interval retry policy.

Reference MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling?tabs=consumption) for retry policy.